# match query datetime in database ms access

Tags: c#, ms-access

hi i have datetime format in database access like this

```
1/18/2014 4:14:52 PM (M/DD/YYYY h/mm/ss)
```

when i tried to select query whith this following code

```
Global.dbCon.Open();
  string kalimatsql2 = "SELECT * FROM Quiz_Occurrences WHERE Occurred = " +dt2+ " 
                            ORDER BY ID";
  Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatsql2);
  if (Global.reader.HasRows) {
     while (Global.reader.Read()) {
        int idku = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));
        MessageBox.Show(idku.ToString());
     }
  }
  Global.dbCon.Close();
```

it's give error result
**Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Occurred = 1/12/2014 4:18:59 PM'**
this is my dt2 var

```
DateTime dt2 = (DateTime) myDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value;
```

i already check it many time...that dt has same format as datetime in database
but it's still give that error result....how to query it correctly

---

### edit

this is my Global.riyeder

```
public static OleDbDataReader riyeder(string kalimatSql) {
    dbCmd.CommandText = kalimatSql;
    return dbCmd.ExecuteReader();            
}
```

Comment: In your `Quiz_Occurrences` table is `Occurred` field is in datetime format?

Comment: @Damith yeah it's date/time format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
Global.dbCon.Open();
  string kalimatsql2 = "SELECT * FROM Quiz_Occurrences WHERE Format(DateOccurred, 'mm/dd/yyyy') = Format( '" + dt2+ "', 'mm/dd/yyyy') ORDER BY ID";
  Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatsql2);
  if (Global.reader.HasRows) {
     while (Global.reader.Read()) {
        int idku = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));
        MessageBox.Show(idku.ToString());
     }
  }
  Global.dbCon.Close();
```

Comment: i get result invalid expresion term ')' and some expected ';' & ')'

Comment: Can you check my solution now

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add Format keyword . Can you check now

Comment: now that code can run but after i remove 'value' in 'dt2.value'...but it's give one error 'OleDBException was unhandled - No value given for one or more required parameters'

Comment: dt2 si datetime picker right ? so you need to use dt2.value or dt2.text

Comment: but if .value not removed it's give error system.datetime does not contain a definiton for 'value'

Comment: Actually What is dt2?

Comment: DateTime dt2 = (DateTime) myDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value;

Comment: i get it from database access...i store it in datagridview cell

Comment: then use like dt2.ToString()

Comment: hm...i still get OleDBException was unhandled - No value given for one or more required parameters' when i use dt2.ToString()
i already post my 'excecutereader' maybe problem in there...may u kind check it...because i really don't have idea to fix

Comment: but i really doubt problem in there because my another query run smooth

Answer (score 1):

You are missing single quotes for value for attribute **Occurred**. it should be

```
 string kalimatsql2 = "SELECT * FROM Quiz_Occurrences WHERE Occurred = '" +dt2+ "' 
                            ORDER BY ID";
```

Comment: i get error 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression' in executeReader....although i already set occured type to date/time...do you have idea why it's happen?

Comment: I feel thats error is in your query. Please debug your code get value for variable **kalimatsql2**.  copy and paste query in sql server and run. so you are confirmed that you query is correct.