# How to pass dates to JSP

Tags: jsp, date

I am doing my mini project and I want to display all record whose date value between today and yesterday. Please find my code below.
I am getting error Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression, but gives result if I have date in format 2014-04-19 but date is not displayed if 19/04/14. I am entering date in dd/mm/yy format in database. 
Please help. I am desperate and tried many codes.I am new to jsp and using jsp and msacess.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>JSP Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <%


    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

       String sSql ="SELECT ADDRESS,FinancialYear,Todate from backup where         DateValue(Todate) BETWEEN DateValue(DATE()) and DateValue(DATE()-1)";
      String sDBQ = "C://Users/vishnu priya/Documents/amc.mdb";
       String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + sDBQ + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true";
       Connection cn = null;
     Statement st = null;
      ResultSet rs = null;

      try {
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","");
       st = cn.createStatement();
      rs=st.executeQuery(sSql);
    %>
    <table border='2' vspace='80'>
       <%
       out.println("<thead>");
      out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<th>Customer Name</th>");
        out.println("<th>Financial Year</th>");
         out.println("<th>To Date</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
      out.println(" </thead>");
      String add="";
       String fin="";
       String to="";
       while(rs.next())
   {
      add=rs.getString(1);
      fin=rs.getString(2);
    to=rs.getString(3);

        %>
       <tr>


      <td><%=add%></td>
       <td><%=fin%></td>
       <td><%=to%></td>
        <%
       }
     out.close();

       }
       catch(Exception e)
     {
     out.println(e);
     }
       %>
</body>
   </html>
```

Please find my output :

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data
>   type mismatch in criteria expression. Customer Name   Financial Year
>     To Date Department of tourism park view, tvm    2012-2013   2014-04-18
>   Amaravila chudukal production cum sale co-operative society ltd.
>   Neyyatinkara, tvm     2013-2014   18-04-2014

Comment: Instead of rs.getString(3) y dont you use rs.getDate("Todate")

Comment: try this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396615/match-query-datetime-in-database-ms-access

Comment: Iam using jsp not C#.Kindly share what to do next .